# Google App Engine upload fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Trying to upload simple hello world app, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "./appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4083, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4074, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2544, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3830, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2991, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2974, in UpdateVersion
    lambda path: self.opener(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2131, in DoUpload
    resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 355, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 326, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 379, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 437, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 281, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 233, in _GetAuthToken
    e.headers, response_dict)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/coder/Go/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.reason = args["Error"]
```

AttributeError: can't set attribute

The e-mail and password are correct. The app works perfectly on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

OK, finally I found the solution - a very simple one:
it appears that google appp engine is not satisfied with the regular account password, it needs the application-specific one which can be set up here: 
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&answer=185833&rd=3